# Jquery unobstrusive validation while binding radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, binding, radio-button, jquery-validate

I have a form which asks user to select `Yes or No` based on some questions.Intitally none of the option will be selected.If user clicks `save` button without selecting the option validation should be shown

```
 <div>
    <label for="IsSourceCodeCollected" class=" control-label">
          Question 1
    </label>
</div>
 <div>
     <label style="width:100px">
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.StudentProjectApprovalTrainer.IsSourceCodeCollected, true, new { @class = "minimal sourceCodeCollected" })
            YES
    </label>
   <label style="width:100px">
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.StudentProjectApprovalTrainer.IsSourceCodeCollected, false, new { @class = "minimal sourceCodeCollected" })
           NO
   </label>
</div>
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StudentProjectApprovalTrainer.IsSourceCodeCollected)

 <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-info pull-left ">
   <i class="fa  fa-save"></i>
        Save
 </button>
```

**Model**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select this")]        
public bool IsSourceCodeCollected { get; set; }
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnSubmit", function () {
    var form = $("#frmAdd");       
    if (form.valid()) {
        alert("hai");
    };     
    return false;
});
```

When I clicks the save button without selecting `Yes or No` alert is shown which means form is valid.

How can i solve this scenario ??

Comment: Not sure what our claiming here. Your binding to property `IsSourceCodeCollected` of `StudentProjectApprovalTrainer` and `IsSourceCodeCollected` is a `bool` which means that one of the radio buttons will be **always** be selected when the view is rendered because its initial value is either `true` or `false` (and cannot be anything else)

Comment: If on the other hand, you do want to initially display no selected buttons, then you can make your property nullable (`bool? IsSourceCodeCollected`) which means if the user does not select one, the validation message will be displayed when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks mate changing from `boo`l to `bool?` solved the issue.Can you post the answer so that it would help other newbies like me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is typeof `bool` which must always have a value (adding the `[Required]` attribute is not necessary unless you wanted a specific error message). Because its value is either `true` or `false`, one of your radio buttons will always be selected when the view is first rendered (and its not possible to 'un-select' both) so the model is always valid.

If you want the option to display both buttons as un-selected and have the validation error display if left un-selected, then you need to change the property to be `nullable`.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select this")]        
public bool? IsSourceCodeCollected { get; set; }
```